# How to find the crash with crash log in crittercism?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, crittercism

The crash log in crittersicm is as mentioned below:

```
 Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
 Exception Reason: SEGV_ACCERR

0  libobjc.A.dylib 0x38a33b36 objc_msgSend + 22
1  UIKit  0x30937739 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 4945
2  CoreFoundation  0x2e18d183 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
3  CoreFoundation  0x2e18c653 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 207 
4  CoreFoundation  0x2e18ae47 __CFRunLoopRun + 623
5  CoreFoundation  0x2e0f5c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
6  CoreFoundation  0x2e0f5a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
7  GraphicsServices  0x32df6283 GSEventRunModal + 139
8  UIKit  0x30999049 UIApplicationMain + 1137
9  xyzApp  0x0002f22f 0x0001e000 + 70191
10  xyzApp  0x000256c8 0x0001e000 + 30408

Thread: Unknown Name

0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe483c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib 0x38f24f9b _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 39
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation 0x2e18c7c3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 155
2   CoreFoundation 0x2e18aee9 __CFRunLoopRun + 785
3   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
4   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   Foundation 0x2eb302f7 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 319
6   Foundation 0x2eba5c87 __NSThread__main__ + 1063
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38ff7440 __select + 20
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation 0x2e18c7c3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 155
2   CoreFoundation 0x2e18aee9 __CFRunLoopRun + 785
3   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
4   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   WebCore 0x362e526b _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 419
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation 0x2e18c7c3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 155
2   CoreFoundation 0x2e18aee9 __CFRunLoopRun + 785
3   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
4   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   libAVFAudio.dylib 0x2d178589 _ZN20GenericRunLoopThread5EntryEPv + 129
6   libAVFAudio.dylib 0x2d16c99f _ZN9CAPThread5EntryEPS_ + 179
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation 0x2e18c7c3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 155
2   CoreFoundation 0x2e18aee9 __CFRunLoopRun + 785
3   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
4   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   xyzApp 0x000a1693 0x0001e000 + 538259
6   Foundation 0x2eba5c87 __NSThread__main__ + 1063
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38ff6f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x39060005 pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   JavaScriptCore 0x2f11ad55 _ZN3JSC14BlockAllocator22blockFreeingThreadMainEv + 209
3   JavaScriptCore 0x2f1183a3 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38ff6f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x39060005 pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   JavaScriptCore 0x2f2b623b _ZN3JSC8GCThread16waitForNextPhaseEv + 79
3   JavaScriptCore 0x2f2b6295 _ZN3JSC8GCThread12gcThreadMainEv + 53
4   JavaScriptCore 0x2f1183a3 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation 0x2e18c7c3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 155
2   CoreFoundation 0x2e18aee9 __CFRunLoopRun + 785
3   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
4   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
5   WebCore 0x3632dd5f _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 255
6   JavaScriptCore 0x2f1183a3 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38ff6f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x39060005 pthread_cond_wait + 41
2   JavaScriptCore 0x2f11ae87 _ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexEd + 63
3   WebCore 0x364183ad _ZN3WTF12MessageQueueINS_8FunctionIFvvEEEE33waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeoutIFbPS3_EEENS_10PassOwnPtrIS3_EERNS_22MessageQueueWaitResultERT_d + 109
4   WebCore 0x36418333 _ZN7WebCore13StorageThread16threadEntryPointEv + 167
5   JavaScriptCore 0x2f1183a3 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 15
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation 0x2e18c7c3 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 155
2   CoreFoundation 0x2e18aee9 __CFRunLoopRun + 785
3   CoreFoundation 0x2e0f5c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
4   CoreFoundation 0x2e13973b CFRunLoopRun + 99
5   CoreMotion 0x2e7ac235 CLSF_thorntonUpdate_6x6 + 57045
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4adc semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   MediaToolbox 0x2f5e1841 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1757
2   CoreMedia 0x2e720237 figThreadMain + 195
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4a8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   MediaToolbox 0x2f5e7c5d FigExpressNotificationThread + 89
2   CoreMedia 0x2e720237 figThreadMain + 195
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38ff7c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc84 start_wqthread + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38ff7c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc84 start_wqthread + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x38fe4adc semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   MediaToolbox 0x2f5e1841 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1757
2   CoreMedia 0x2e720237 figThreadMain + 195
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fc1d _pthread_body + 141
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905fb8f _pthread_start + 103
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3905dc90 thread_start + 8
```

xyzApp is the placeholder for the app name. I m unable to replicate the crash .
Please help me out. This crash is present in the ipa that is uploaded to App Store with live url(production url). It is a universal app.

Just for reference:
Device details for which the crsh has occurred:
DEVICE
3rd Gen iPad, CDMA
OS
iOS7.0.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace from Crittercism?

Comment: @JeremiahEdwards I have edited and added all the threads that were mentioned in crittercism under this crash.

Comment: You need to symbolicate that crash log to convert the addresses in your app to source file name/line numbers. However in your case the two symbols are almost certainly just `_start` and `_main` as your app doesn't directly call any API method near the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't symbolicated. That helps a lot when debugging with Crittercism. Here's the documentation Crittercism provides around getting the symbols onto the server for iOS:

http://docs.crittercism.com/ios/ios.html#configuring-ios-symbolication

If you're having trouble uploading symbols to Crittercism, then contacting there support might be your best bet.